# Special characters and StrConv

Tags: vba, strconv

i have an xls with text in different languages, which include also german, greek, and so on.

I have to copy these texts to a html file.

The resulting text is not shown as expected, with special characters, like umlauts or greek characters.

For example: i have a cell with the word "öko"

Using something like:(to read)

```
test = Cells("36", "D").Value
```

and(to write):

```
fso.WriteLine ("<title>" & StrConv(test, vbUnicode) & "</title>")
```

what i see as title in the html file is **??k?o?**.

Do i have to install or configure something in my system?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have solved creating the file with the following Statement:     **Set ts_html_de = fso_html_de.CreateTextFile(Path_HTML_de, True, True)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed a parameter in your OpenTextFile call. If the fourth parameter is -1, then it is Unicode.

Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: yes, i did. Now i am testing with this Parameter, thanks